# Was there ever a kilowatt workstation?

Tags: power, workstation

Back in the day, workstations used to get impressively big. Take a look at [this](https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-alphaserver-ds20e-alpha-21264-833-mhz-1-gb-0-gb/specs/) — sure, a modern laptop has more computing power, but you don't see personal computers weighing eighty pounds these days.

I'm interested in power consumption and heat dissipation (sadly not listed for the above machine). In particular, did any workstation ever go over a kilowatt of thermal design power? For this purpose, I'm classifying a computer as a workstation if it's quiet enough that you'd want it under your desk, and a server if it's noisy enough that you'd want it in a separate room. So another way of phrasing the question is, did anyone ever manage to dissipate more than a kilowatt with air cooling through a tower form factor, and still keep it quiet?

Comment: You definitely wouldn’t want an AlphaServer (the system you linked to) under your desk! It’s not a workstation. It’s worth noting that many workstations were quite noisy back in the eighties and nineties...

Comment: Your question wanders into the ambiguous territory of where the distinction between a workstation and a minicomputer lies.  A lot of minicomputers consumed more than 1kW (A quick google suggests that various versions of PDP-11 could consume between 1.2kW and 6kW, for instance).  And while they were generally designed and used for multi-user applications, some were used for single user purposes, so could plausibly be called workstations... see http://www.wolfgang-houben.de/faqpdp11.htm and search for "MicroPDP" for example.

Comment: What do you mean by "did". [Here](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/ax1500i-digital-atx-power-supply-1500-watt-fully-modular-psu) is a 1.5 kW gaming PSU. [Here](http://mullet.se/product.html?product_id=337156) is a modern 2 kW workstation (Gibberish in Swedish, sorry).

Comment: @pipe - there's a difference between PSU maximum output and thermal dissipation.  It's common to allow relatively large amounts of spare capacity on the basis that PSUs produce better regulated output when they're not approaching their limits.  That 2kW workstation, for example, has 2 CPUs @ 135W each + up to 4x GPU boards, which tend to max out at 150W each.  Allowing another 100W for other components, that's *just* short of 1kW TDP.

Comment: (... that said, I recall that NVidia produce or produced a system intended to allow 8 GPU boards to be installed, which would definitely exceed 1kW; I'm not convinced it was ever intended for use as a workstation, though, but rather as part of a high performance cluster)

Comment: @Jules Right, like I said, the distinction I'm proposing to use is that a workstation is quiet enough that you wouldn't mind having it under your desk. (Apparently the AlphaServer didn't meet that criterion!) Doesn't seem to say anything about noise level of the MicroPDP?

Comment: @Jules, "Workstation" is easy to define:  It's a station (i.e., something you don't normally move from place-to-place) where _one person_ works.  "Minicomputer" is harder to define, but some historical computers (e.g., [Xerox Alto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_Alto), [Lisp Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine) easily fit into both categories.

Comment: @Jules PCI-Express GPUs go higher than 150W, for example the Quadro P6000 (an available option on the linked 2kW workstation) has a TDP of 250W, while the Radeon RX Vega 64 Liquid is an insane 345W. You can easily build a 1000W+ TDP PC out of off-the-shelf parts these days.

Comment: @RossRidge - both of those cards are double width and therefore effectively occupy two slots due to the size of the heatsinks on them, so AFAICS you'd only be able to get two of them into the system linked.  I could be wrong about that, though.

Comment: @Jules You can see from the picture on the webpage that the workstation can fit four two-slot GPUs. http://mullet.se/PICTURE/150901-4-sys-7048gr-tr.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SGI Onyx and related machines were made in a "deskside" version.

Let us look at the specifications from this manual ...

https://techpubs.jurassic.nl/library/manuals/1000/007-1733-070/pdf/007-1733-070.pdf "POWER Onyx™ and Onyx Deskside Owner’s Guide"

8100BTU/h max Thermal dissipation for the whole system. That is 2.4kW, concurrent with the rated power for the version equipped with the "Infinite Reality" graphics subsystem.

Given these were professional use machines typically used for rendering animated video using the complex graphics hardware, it is unlikely they were not designed to run under full load for extended periods of time. It is also unlikely that the power supplies were overbuilt "just because", since their rating brings the inconvenience of being beyond what a standard 120V wall socket can deliver.

Noise is rated at 60dB.

https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/SiliconGraphics+Onyx+Teardown/12546 .. these huge boxes were filled with mostly electronics, not air :)

Comment: *"their rating brings the inconvenience of being beyond what a standard 120V wall socket can deliver"* -- yes, but well within the capabilities of a 220/240v supply, which I believe is usually available in commercial premises even in the US? *"Noise is rated at 60dB."* which is a little quieter than the fan heater I use to warm my office up ... and a little *more* effective at heating. :)

Comment: Not by much. A computer turns all the power into heat, excepting power used to send communications signals (which will the heat someone else's office), energy consumed to make magnetic changes on media, energy used to power indicator lights or sounds (most of the light end ends up as heat too), energy to move air (will end up as heat somewhere else too).

Comment: Was there a 240V socket usually available in an office used for animation work in the 1990s, or would it have meant "call a sparky and maybe have the socket 3 weeks later"?

Comment: Most US and Canada commercial or industrial buildings are wired for "three-phase" power, in which 120V and 208V, but not 240V, can be easily made available. 208 uses the same outlets as 240, but are only installed where requested. They're common enough in laboratory and mechanical spaces; occasionally they can be spotted in corridors for use by floor polishing machines. Otherwise you'd need to have one installed. But equally easy would be a 20-amp 120-volt circuit, from which I believe 1.9 kW sustained load could be supported.

Comment: @CCTO my point was, anything that can't be relied on being available in a business building and which will need to be professionally installed....

Comment: Hi rackandboneman. Yes, sorry if I wasn't to the point. 120V 20A and 208V 15A or 20A are exactly that: not likely to be available until requested, but usually installable on request, in typical office space in US&Can.

Comment: @CCTO Why can’t they have 240V from a split-phase line like US residential lines? (Especially as both residential and commercial lines come from the same grid sources, right?)

Comment: @Dai: Given three-phase power at distribution voltage, transformers can fairly easily be designed to produce six balanced phases, 60 degrees apart.  If a customer needed all six phases, it wouldn't be particularly hard to supply them, but for most purposes either two or three would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't make sense in its actual state. 'Thermal design power' is nonsense term when taking about a computer (in fact it's even more when it's about CPUs). Computers are neither designed to do mechanical work, light rooms or alike. There is no physical computing power - the only physical output is heat and a little bit of HF radiation.

**So the only usefull question I to be found would be *'have there been desktopcomputers with more than 1 kW power rating'*.**

And the answer is **Yes**, quite a lot.

Already the IMSAI PS was rated at 500 Watt primary, and it didn't take long for third party frames to offer PS with 1 kW primry and more. And primary is a key issue here. Before the advent of switching, the power supply itself was usually the most critical part. In case of above IMSAI, up to 2/3rd of the primary power was wasted to heat up the PS. Removing that substantial heat was also needed to protect the PS, not so much the CPU.

Watercooling in computers was also not introduced to keep computing chips cool, but their transformers and power electronics. For example, a SIEMENS 7.760 X4 CPU, an upper end /370ish machine of ~1980 had a watercooled power supply, but air cooled electronics.

Even with a switching PS, like the Apple II pionered, the PS stayed the main heat source within the case. Kensington made good money with their system saver series of add on fans. It took many years until the computing chips itself got miniaturized enough to need even a simple head spreader for the little power they transformed.

Comment: Given the >70% efficiency typically quoted for PSMPS, and the fact that, as you mentioned, practically all power consumed by a computer is turned into heat, considering the PSU the main heat source (by amount of heat, not heat concentration!) is illogical. And BTW: ELRAD magazine once published a linear PSU design claiming PSMPS-level efficiency for external drives.

Comment: @rackandboneman Well, efficency at 70% or above was wishful tinking back then. The Apple II PS did manage less than 60% at full load. Without a date and reference he claim about linear vs. switching doesn't make any sense. Then again, specialized linear designs could go well up to 50% when used at peak effiency - and switchign designs of the 70 often did't do much. So yeah, comparing a race donkey with a Clydesdale does make a lot of sense ...

Comment: The Apple II is considered a very atypical SMPS design, no? HP quotes 70% for the PSU in the 2640A terminal, from 1975... 2100A from 1971 is 800W input rated at 500W output, which still makes >60% ...